# Issue with variable concatenation in postgres using copy from command

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to insert a number of text files with json data into a database. Each file is is suffixed with 1,2,3... etc. (shapes_routes1.json, shapes_routes2.json etc.). To do this I am concatenating an index to the base file name from within a loop. I am getting this error:

```
psql:insertshapes.sql:37: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "file_path"
LINE 17: copy temp_json from file_path;
```

Can you not supply `copy from` with a variable as the path? Or is there something I need to do to the variable (file_path) so psql knows its a path?
Any help or recommendations on this would be appreciated.

```
 delete from shapes;

    DO $$

    declare
        n INTEGER := 1;
        prefix TEXT := '/Users/me/model/json/filechunks/shapes_routes';
        i TEXT := NULL;
        file_path TEXT := NULL;

    BEGIN
    LOOP 
    EXIT WHEN n = 166;
    i := CAST(n as TEXT);
    file_path := prefix || i || '.json';
    n := n + 1;

    create temporary table temp_json (values text);
    copy temp_json from file_path; --GETTING ERROR ON THIS LINE
    insert into shapes

    select  values->>'shape_id' as shape_id,
            (CAST(values->>'shape_pt_lat' as real)) as shape_pt_lat,
            (CAST(values->>'shape_pt_lon' as real)) as shape_pt_lon,
            (CAST(values->>'shape_pt_sequence' as integer)) as shape_pt_sequence,
            (CAST(values->>'shape_dist_traveled' as real)) as shape_dist_traveled,
            values->>'route_id' as route_id

    from   (
            select json_array_elements(replace(values,'\','\\')::json) as values 
            from   temp_json
           ) a;

    drop table temp_json;
    END LOOP; 
    END $$;
```

Comment: If the files are, like you said, `shapes_routes1.json` `shapes_routes2.json` ... Why are you concatenating a `/` on its name? It will make the name as `/Users/me/model/json/filechunks/shapes_routes/1.json` and not the names you mention...

Comment: I don't know :) long day. Thanks

Comment: The error remains the same as expected.

Comment: Unrelated, but: it will be much more efficient, if you create the temp table **once** before the loop and `truncate` it before each import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COPY requires a string literal, you can't use a subselect for the filename.

if you need to you need to vary the filename you'll need to use dynamic sql,
( `EXECUTE` )

eg:

```
EXECUTE 'copy temp_json from '||quote_literal(file_path);
```

Comment: I am getting this error now after putting EXECUTE copy from etc.

Comment: psql:insertshapes.sql:38: ERROR:  relation "file_path" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT copy temp_json from file_path
                                   ^
QUERY:  SELECT copy temp_json from file_path
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 18 at EXECUTE

Comment: Does this mean it can't find the file or it can't see variable file_path?

Comment: execute can't see variables.

Comment: Thanks man that worked! You're a champ. That was driving me bananas